# Not able to send json object to servlet

Tags: json, servlets, gson

Here i am calling servlet through AJAX Call from JSP.In servlet ,fetching data from DB and Converting these data to JSON Format using Gson.After that i want to send this json object to this JSP.But here i am not able to send json object.Please suggest Me?
Here code for AJAX Call :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#subbtn').click(function(event) {     
                console.log("Hello");
                var searchfield = $('#searchfields').val();
                var operator = $('#operator').val();
                var fieldvalue = $('#searchstring').val();
                var filter=searchfield+operator+"'"+fieldvalue+"'";
                console.log(filter);
                $.get('SearchData', {
                    filter : filter

                }, function(responseText) {
                    $('#example').html(responseText);

                    console.log('dddd');
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Here is servlet COde  :

```
String query = "select * from searchsample";
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            renderingengine = resultSet.getString("RenderingEngine");
            browser = resultSet.getString("Browser");
            platform = resultSet.getString("platform");
            engineversion = resultSet.getString("EngineVersion");
            cssgrade = resultSet.getString("CSSGrade");
        }

         Gson gson = new Gson();

       JsonVo jsondata=new JsonVo();
       jsondata.setRenderingengine(renderingengine);
       jsondata.setBrowser(browser);
       jsondata.setPlatform(platform);
       jsondata.setEngineversion(engineversion);
       jsondata.setCssgrade(cssgrade);
       String toJson = gson.toJson(jsondata);
        System.out.println("Json Format : " +toJson);

        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need write below line to send `JSON` to `JSP` from `servlet`.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(toJson);
```